# Can we perform an ACTION programmatically on a Notification from Notification Listener Service?

Tags: android, service, notifications, action

Is it possible to invoke an ACTION programatically on a Notification from a NotificationListenerService? 
I have written a Notification Listener service that reads out all the incoming notifications and dismisses when done. But I'm not sure if we can perform any ACTIONs on the incoming notifications.

For eg: On a WhatsApp message notification I can read the package name, sender and message details but is there a way to send a reply back to the sender? 
Currently Android Wear is doing this so I'm wondering if it is following a generic approach of acting upon a Notification or it has a specific API to WhatsApp service.

Answer (score 2):

When ever a whatsapp notification is received via notification listerner service there is one another notification thats received (hidden) which has a tag value something like this XXXXXXX@s.whatsapp.net (xxxxxxx being the phonenumber), I think this somehow holds the key to sending a reply to this user.

I am working on other app logic, which does not require you to send back replies but I found this interesting but could not get enough time to check it myself.

Comment: the tag isn't a number for me....its a long string like this: "tNLx2UI8P1zatLErXwwLOekJ8mmQUA7yA2rKg4eoe8U="

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can do it by this function:

```
sbn.notification.actions[0].actionIntent.send()
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, we can perform actions on notifications. Pushbullet app on Android has an ability to reply to WhatsApp, Hangouts, Facebook messenger etc when user enters the message form desktop which means that there is a way. I am still trying to figure out how to do it.

Comment: i think the Android Wear app is only required for Hangouts replies. I've been trying to figure it out as well but haven't had much luck. I can add the action buttons to the notification but can't find a way to actually reply or mark as read. Any ideas?